# Can't add custom option to product programmatically

Tags: php, magento

I have code which creates a product and then adds custom options to it.
But if I open it in the admin panel, no custom options are added. Also, no error message or warnings are generated. My Magento version is 1.9.1.0. 
What is the problem with the script?

```
$sku = 'test2';
$name = 'Test Product';
$description = 'Test Product Description';
$shortdescription = 'Test Product Short Description';
$price = '100';
$specialprice = '80';
$specialfromdate = '08/20/2014';
$specialtodate = '08/22/2014';
$categoryids = array(3,4,5);
$taxClassId = 0;    // None
$visibility = 4;    // catalog, search
$productStatus = 1;    // enabled
$createdDate = '08/20/2014';
$updatedDate = '08/20/2014';
//$imagepath = 'C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Chrysanthemum.jpg';    //    absolute path of image in local file system/server path
$color = 7;    //    Dropdown Attribute i.e 7 is attribute option id
$brand = '13,14,16';    //    Multiselect Attribute must be pass as string i.e 13,14 and 16 are attribute option's id


$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->setSku($sku);
$product->setName($name);
$product->setDescription($description);
$product->setShortDescription($shortdescription);
//$product->setUrlKey($data['5']);    //    Uncomment only if custom url type
$product->setPrice($price);
$product->setSpecialPrice($specialprice);
$product->setSpecialFromDate($specialfromdate);
$product->setSpecialToDate($specialtodate);
$product->setTypeId('simple');
$product->setAttributeSetId(4); // enter the catalog attribute set id here
//$product->addImageToMediaGallery($imagepath,'image',true,false); // absolute path of image in local file system
$product->setCategoryIds($categoryids); // id of categories
$product->setWeight(1.0);
$product->setTaxClassId($taxClassId);
$product->setVisibility($visibility);
$product->setStatus($productStatus);
$product->setColor($color);
$product->setBrand($brand);
$product->setStockData(
array(
'manage_stock' => 1,
'is_in_stock' => 1,
'qty' => 100
)
);
// assign product to the default website
$product->setWebsiteIds(array(Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getWebsite()->getId()));
//$product->setCreatedAt($createdDate);    //    uncomment if add custom date
//$product->setUpdatedAt($updatedDate);    //    uncomment if add custom date
try
{
/*  Add custom options */
$sizes = array(M,L,XL,XXL);
if(count(array_filter($sizes)) > 0){
$options = array();
$optionData = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($sizes); $i++){
$options[$i]['is_delete'] = '';
$options[$i]['title'] = $sizes[$i];
$options[$i]['price_type'] = 'fixed';
$options[$i]['price'] = '';
$options[$i]['sku'] = '';
}

$optionData = array(
'is_delete'         => 0,
'is_require'        => false,
'previous_group'    => '',
'title'             => 'Size',
'type'              => 'drop_down',
'sort_order'        => 1,
'values'            => $options
);

$optionInstance = $product->getOptionInstance()->unsetOptions();

$product->setHasOptions(1);
$optionInstance->addOption($optionData);
$optionInstance->setProduct($product);

}
/*  ------------------- */
$product->getResource()->save($product);
echo $product->getId().'  Save Successfully';
}
catch (Exception $ex) {
echo $ex->getMessage();
//Handle the error
}
```

Comment: Removed excess, Reworded for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is about 5 years too late...

TL/DR:
By using `$product->getResourceModel()->save()` you are skipping the code that is responsible for saving custom options on a product. If you use `$product->save()` instead it will save your custom options during the Mage_Catalog_Model_Product _afterSave() method.

Long Version:
The code that saves custom options during a product save is actually defined in Mage_Catalog_Model_Product's _afterSave() (line #546 as of version 1.9.4.3) method which is called during `$product->save()` (defined in Mage_Core_Model_Abstract which if you follow the inheritance chain, you will find Mage_Catalog_Model_Product eventually inherits from). So by going straight to the resource model (`$product->getResourceModel()->save()`) you are actually skipping the code that is responsible for saving those custom options.

Answer (score 0):

I would first make sure that the attribute has been created and contains all of the custom options you're trying to add programmatically. Otherwise the product may attempt to create options/values that don't exist.

https://www.mymagento.com/index.php/admin/catalog_product_attribute/